# Find element with unique content then grab content of next element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to get the content of the element after `dt` that has certain content that is nowhere else on the page. What method should I use?

```
<dt>This is the first element</dt>
<dd>This is to be returned</dd>
```

Comment: I would assume something like a for loop over `document.querySelector('dt')` checking if `innerHtml = 'unique content'`, and then calling `nextSiblingElement`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that question. This question references how to locate the next element based on a particular condition of the preceeding element, not just how to target a succeeding element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to find the `dd` element's content based on the `dt` element's content, you could loop over the node list of `dt` elements in the page like this:

```
function getVal() {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('dt');
    var returnVal = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        if (els[i].innerText == contentToMatch) {    // check 'dt' content
            returnVal = els[i].nextSibling.innerText;    // get 'dd' content
            break;
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

This function will return `false` if that specific content is not found.  You can also substitute `innerHTML` for `innerText`, depending on what you're looking for.